# How to enable Networking inside a `systemd-nspawn` container?

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, network-bridge, container

How can I get networking to work inside a `systemd-nspawn` container in Ubuntu 20.04? I want the container to get an IP address from local DHCP server, perform DNS lookups using my configured name server, and have WAN/LAN connectivity.

I start the container as follows:

```
sudo systemd-nspawn --private-network --bind-ro="/etc/resolv.conf" --machine="TEST" --directory="<path_to_root>"
```

Note, I can remove `--private-network` from the above command to get it to work, but then my container has the same IP address as my host machine, and this is not what I want.

**resolv.conf**

On my host machine `resolv.conf` points to `stub-resolv.conf`:

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

Its contents is:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search local
```

My local network name server is `192.168.1.1`.

**IP Addresses**

If I execute the command, `ip addr` inside the container, this is the output:

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can see that an IP address was not assigned to the container by my network's DHCP server, since the address should start with 192.168.

If I execute the command, `ip addr` on my host machine, this is the output:

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:a8:a6:7f:9d:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.122/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 251661sec preferred_lft 251661sec
    inet6 fe80::ae8d:74ba:b255:6db3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**DNS Lookups**

DNS lookups do not work:

```
ping www.ubuntu.com
ping: www.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I get a "Network unreachable" error if I try to ping known IP addresses on my local network or the Internet:

```
ping 8.8.8.8    
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

Oddly, I am able to successfully ping *any* IP address that starts with `127.0.0.???`. (I don't know if that is relevant, but I thought I'd mention it).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have a similar issue.

Comment: No resolution yet.